# How can I push the primefaces DefaultMenuModel before an accordion panel?

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I'm having a DefaultMenuModel inside a tab from an accordion panel.

Now the menu is behind the tab of an acccordion panel and I like to change the z-index of the menu, that it will be in front of the tab.

It looks like:

[image: the image below shows the result:]

I tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/templates/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="window_title"/>
   <ui:define name="content">
  <h:form id="exportForm" style="height:100%">
     <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
        <p:accordionPanel id="memberPanel" multiple="true" activeIndex="1" styleClass="test1">
        <p:tab title="#{messages['member_filter']}">
        <table>
           <tr valign="top">
              <td>#{messages['export_filter']} <br></br> 
                    <p:tieredMenu styleClass="test2" id="type" model="#{dynamicFilterMenuExport.menu}" />
              </td>
              <td><p:spacer width="10" /></td>
              <td>#{messages['export_filter_select']}<br></br>
              <br></br> <!-- more Code-->
           </tr>
        </table>
     </p:tab>
     <p:tab title="#{messages['menu_Members']}" >
     <!-- datatable etc. -->
     </p:tab>
     </p:accordionPanel>
  </h:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

My css looks like:

```
.test1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}

.test2 {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2000 !important;
   overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching I found out the answer be adjusting the css.
Now it's working perfectly with the code below:

```
.ui-accordion-content {
   overflow:visible !important;
}
```